# can't install difflib and urllib.parse on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I don't manage to install `difflib` and `urllib.parse` packages for `Python 2.7.10` on `Win7` machine.

From cmd:

> C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install -U difflib Downloading/unpacking
>   difflib
> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement
>   difflib
> Cleaning up... 
> No distributions at all found for difflib

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to install either; [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) is right there in the standard library, and `urllib.parse` is the *Python 3 version* for the Python 2 [`urlparse` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). Why are you trying to install these at all?

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters! For some reason I thought that in order to use them I need to install them from a repository.

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get install npm

npm install difflib
```